# Loading a jQuery plugin from the Libraries 2.X module in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, javascript

I am using the jQuery Easing plugin (http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) for one of my Drupal 7 themes. I see that there is a Libraries module that loads this plugin in a way that allows other modules and themes to use it: http://drupal.org/project/jqeasing.

Is this the correct way to load the library?

After loading the library, Do I need to explicitly call drupal add js from the template.php theme file? The documentation for the Libraries module for theme development is terrible. I may contribute to it, once I get this sorted out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea using a module that exposes it as a library is totally the way to go.

And you certainly don't want to use `drupal_add_js` because `drupal_add_library`  [[link]](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_library/7) will do it the proper way.

And for your case:

```
drupal_add_library('jqeasing', 'easing');
```

Comment: Just an after thought, it would be really cool if you could put a **library** in the theme's .info file. You could add it in the `scripts[]` array, but it isn't really proper.

Comment: I have this in my template.php for my Drupal 7 theme -  

`function Mytheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  if (drupal_is_front_page()) {

 drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path("theme", "Mytheme") . "/test.js");  
 drupal_add_library("jqeasing", "easing");
  
   }
}
`

It's loading my test.js file on the frontpage, but not the jqeasing library. Am I missing something?

Comment: You may be able to do it with just `drupal_add_library("jqeasing");`

Answer (score -1):

inside the template.php file

```
Mytheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) { if (drupal_is_front_page()) { libraries_load("easing"); } }
```